# Посоветуйте angular 2/4/5 datepicker с регулируемым количеством показываемых месяцев

Tags: javascript, css, angular2, typescript, datepicker

Кто-нибудь знает простой **angular 2/4/5 datepicker**, где можно изменять количество отображаемых месяцев (**multiple month**) и выбирать только одну дату?

[примерно как на этом изображении](http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-B8f6lHdHVNw/UXfvO6LsTFI/AAAAAAAAAHo/-qPK-qZx-hY/s640/How+to+Show+multiple+months+in+datepicker+calendar+control+using+jQuery+in+c%23.jpg)

Только здесь есть возможность менять месяц стрелочками.

А всё, что мне нужно - три месяца и выбор одной даты!

Answer (score 1):

[Pikaday](https://github.com/dbushell/Pikaday)

[image: Pikaday]

Не Angular компонент, но легковесный и без зависимостей от jQuery. А в компонент можно и самому обернуть. Количество отображаемых месяцев задается свойством `numberOfMonths` при создании.

```
let picker = new Pikaday({
    field: document.getElementById('datepicker'),
    numberOfMonths: 3
});
```